# Disable global installs using pip - allow only virtualenvs

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Sometimes by mistake, I install some packages globally with plain `pip install package` and contaminate my system instead of creating a proper virtualenv and keeping things tidy.

How can I easily disable global installs with `pip` at all?

Or at least show a big warning when using it this way to ensure I know what I am doing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I can be late, but you can do it either via:

1. config (`~/.pip/pip.conf`):

```
[global]
require-virtualenv = true
```

2. env variable `PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV`

This gives you exactly what you want, example:

```
$ pip install foobar
ERROR: Could not find an activated virtualenv (required).
```

Comment: For Windows users, this configuration file is not created automatically. You will have to manually create it in the global location specified by "pip config -v list". The default path is currently "C:\ProgramData\pip\pip.ini"

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating adding something like this to your `.bashrc`

```
pip() {
    if [ -n "$VIRTUAL_ENV" ]; then
        # Run pip install
    else
        echo "You're not in a virtualenv"
    fi
}
```

My knowledge of bash isn't the greatest but this should put you on the right path I think.

Comment: If the OP is about to install a package globally, they must be running `pip` as root, and so either (a) they used `sudo pip ...`, and so their `~/.bashrc` isn't in effect, or (b) they're running in a root shell, in which case the proper way to block dangerous actions is to stop doing that.